Insert a timestamp value into an Oracle table from APEX
I have a form where I'm logging the submitted date and time in a timestamp format.

And I populate this with a default expression.

And my DB table column is a timestamp(6) datatype.
But I get this error when I go to submit via APEX.

If I remove the .ff6 from the format syntax the data does go in but I don't get the timestamp.
8/7/2024 8:37:15.000000 PM


What is the type of the page item and what value have you put in the "format mask" attribute of the page item ?

From my point of view, a simple option is to modify target table and set submitted_dt column's default value.
This is what you have:
SQL> create table test
  2  (id            number constraint pk_test primary key,
  3   name          varchar2(20) not null,
  4   submitted_dt  timestamp
  5  );

Table created.

This is what you should do:
SQL> alter table test modify submitted_dt default localtimestamp;

Table altered.

Does it work?
SQL> insert into test (id, name) values (1, 'Little');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test;

   ID NAME       SUBMITTED_DT
----- ---------- ---------------------------------------------
    1 Little     08.08.24 07:13:18,334661

SQL>

Looks like it does.

Your solumn works if I'm inserting the record via SQL , but I'm trying to insert a record from APEX Form and then read that record back that has a timestamp applied.

Default value works for all kinds of inserts.
